# How to extract common methods into a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to extract common method chains to prevent copy paste the identical code.

How to do it in Javascript way ?

### Original

```
if(this.get('with_coverage')){
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", (width / 2))
      .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
      .style("font-size", "16px") 
      .style("text-decoration", "underline")
      .text("With Coverage");
}
else{
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", (width / 2))             
      .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
      .style("font-size", "16px") 
      .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
      .text("Without Coverage");
}
```

### EXPECTED

```
var apply_style = attr("x", (width / 2))
      .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
      .style("font-size", "16px") 
      .style("text-decoration", "underline");

if(this.get('with_coverage')){
  svg.append("text")
      .apply_style()
      .text("With Coverage");
}
else{
  svg.append("text")
      .apply_style()
      .text("Without Coverage");
}
```

Comment: I could guess smth like `var textVar = svg.append("text").attr("x", (width / 2)).attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2)).attr("text-anchor", "middle").style("font-size", "16px").style("text-decoration", "underline");

if(this.get('with_coverage')){
  textVar.text("With Coverage");
}
else{
  textVar.text("Without Coverage");
}`
will work either. I just don't know this lib. So, just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))
    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .style("font-size", "16px") 
    .style("text-decoration", "underline")
    .text("With"+(this.get('with_coverage')?"":"out")+" Coverage");
```

[Magic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

---

Some people don't like those ternary operators mixed in the code. In that case you can do this:

```
function applyStyleBasedOnCondition(selection, actions, condition, t, f){
    actions.call(selection);
    (condition ? t : f).call(selection);
}

applyStyleBasedOnCondition(svg.append("text"), function(){
   this
      .attr({
          x: width / 2,
          y: 0 - (margin.top / 2),
          "text-anchor": "middle"
      }) 
      .style({
          "font-size": "16px",
          "text-decoration": "underline"
      });
}, this.get('with_coverage'), function(){
     this.text("With Coverage");
}, function(){
     this.text("Without Coverage");
});
```

Comment: what's `.style(` ? i did not see this in jQuery api before.. May be you could have suggested `.css(` instead of that.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - This looks like [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#style).

Answer (score 0):

The chaining is achieved by returning the same object. 
To have `apply_style` method in svg object you could do :

```
svg.apply_style = function(){
   this.attr("x", (width / 2))
       .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
       .style("font-size", "16px") 
       .style("text-decoration", "underline");

   return this;  //important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var svg = d3.select('#svg')

// 1st approach - simple and stable
var circle = function(){
  return svg.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', 100)
    .attr('cy', 100)
    .attr('r', 40)
}

circle()
  .style('fill', 'green')

circle()
  .style('fill', 'red')
  .attr('r', 20)

// 2nd approach - more generic, but not very stable.
// !! Use it carefully !!
d3.selection.prototype.myFillMixin = function(){
  return this.style('fill', '#27F')
    .style('stroke', 'red')
    .style('stroke-width', 4)
    .style('opacity', .7)
}

svg.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 200)
  .attr('y', 200)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .myFillMixin()

svg.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 240)
  .attr('y', 240)
  .myFillMixin() //No matter where to place
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lss0jupb/)